# Multiple processes polling mysql and updating data

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am having an issue with getting mysql and my nodejs app to play along nicely together.  Basically, I have two nodejs "clients" that poll mysql table for 50 rows of data.  However, I do not want them to poll the same 50 rows.  Once one client has it's 50 rows of data, it performs some basic operations and spins up some bash scripts.  It may take a few seconds for this.  All 50 rows of data are updated in the table to indicate those rows are "in-use" on that client.

The problem is, there are situations where both clients request at the same time and receive the same 50 rows.  How do/Can I safely use an innodb lock to lock those rows from being read/used by any other client?  Even when it may take a few seconds to make sure the row data has successfully spun up the scripts?

I'm sort of at a loss and need some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is

```
SELECT columnName FROM tableName FOR UPDATE;
```

This will select a row and lock it so another simultaneous connection can not select it.

See MySql doc [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is what I've been exploring.  Would I need to make the calls in a transaction?  Is there a better way to do the `UPDATE` part for 50 rows at a time?

Answer (score 0):

you can use redis lock to perform such task.

eg: set page size = 50; if you want to get records from 100 ; size = 50; you will need to acquire lock `locks:row:100` for example.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redlock

```
const resource = 'locks:row:100'
const ttl = 1000

redlock.lock(resource, ttl).then(function(lock) {
    // DO STUFF

    return lock.unlock()
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err)
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution
You mention.

> All 50 rows of data are updated in the table to indicate those rows
>   are "in-use" on that client.

I wonder how exactly u are doing this step.. it seems done correctly this method should prove effective.

I would first do

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET lockColumnName='jnodeClientGUID' 
WHERE lockColumnName IS NULL
LIMIT 50
```

Then you could saftey do

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE lockColumnName = 'jnodeClientGUID'
```

You would then have to manage the unlocking of the records appropriately, but this would give you the effect of locking the records over many seconds and should remove issues of race condition.

Though admittedly Im not confident this is the most efficient way.